# Cache HTTP requests in a serverless environment

Tags: http, caching, https, serverless, cache-control

I have an serverless lambda which does the following:

- Start with a set of `ids` in the query (`example.com?ids=a,b,c`)
- Does HTTP request to another webservice (based on the given `ids`) which I do not control
- Renders the website based on the other webservice response

All works, no issues so far.

Today I introduced a new UI for my website. The user can toggle between "a tableview" and "a listview".
Because those differents views can also be controlled via (another) query paramter, I do a simple "redirect" to my own website. Assuming I'm looking currently at the tableview, for the "show listview" textfield I have a simple `<a href="example.com?ids=a,b,c&view=list">[...]<a>`.

This redirect leads, of course, to another call to the "other webservice". Even if I can be pretty sure that the content haven't change since my last call (just a few seconds/minutes ago).

My question is:

Can I somehow cache the HTTP requests from my lambda so that we won't do the call again?
I'm somewhat aware of the `Cache-Control` headers, but since it is an serverless environment it could (and probably will?! I don't know but I don't even care ) another machine without this cache. And therefore it will not be an cache hit and will do the requests anyways.

Please don't answer with solutions like "Use JavaScript for changing the UI". I'm aware that this is possible, but my main question is just how (and even if I can) cache such requests in a serverless environment.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does lambda persist any data in memory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63227135/does-lambda-persist-any-data-in-memory)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caching results of a lambda function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67696424/caching-results-of-a-lambda-function)

Answer (score 0):

From documentation and common best practices we get the impression, that a Serverless function or more specifically an AWS Lambda function has only a very short lifespan. This is to the point, that we need to assume that a function is provisioned into its (firecracker) micro container for a single call only and gets de-provisioned afterwards.

However, to safe resources and to improve performance, the life cycle of a Lambda is rather: provisioning, use for several distinct function calls, de-provisioning.

This means irregardless of the used language, the container gets reused for a [certain amount of time](https://acloudguru.com/blog/engineering/how-long-does-aws-lambda-keep-your-idle-functions-around-before-a-cold-start). Global resources you create in that time (global variables, static objects, files) will survive beyond a single function call.

## Your case

In your exact case you can then implement whichever caching strategy you want. This should work most of the times for your use-case with two pitfalls you need to be aware of:

- The micro container gets re-used between requests *between different clients*. Meaning that of course you need to have a way of access control to your cache, if this is relevant to your use-case.
- You do not have direct control over the timeout time of your Lambda, meaning that you should anticipate that every now and then a user will experience the overhead of a non-cached request just due to bad timing.

Let us know about your final solution.